# SonarQube analysis failed while ruining msbuild runner

Tags: .net, sonarqube, msbuild-4.0, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am running sonarqube msbuild runner on my build server and I am able to begin analysis and build the project but when I **end** I am getting below meassage

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, VS2012 used MSBuild v4.0 which doesn't include the *ImportBefore* mechanism that is used to include the *SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild* integration targets. Try building with a later version of VS, or explicitly import the integration targets into your project.

Answer (score 1):

Which C# plugin version are you using? The latest version (4.4) suggests using MSBuild 12.0 or higher, as well as by running it from Developer Command Prmopt for *VS2013*

Comment: Hi the issue is resolved.I was  using the older version of the MSBuild. and .net framwork version should be 4.5.2